# How retrieve data from websocket?

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, socket.io, mongoose

Please how i can retrieve **data** and **username from** web socket,

`io.sockets.emit('update chat', 'username':socket.username, 'data':data);`

i'm sending data from android to socket then i want retrieve this data in my server chat but i get `[object object]`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use `JSON.stringify` before emiting the `data` variable like

```
io.sockets.emit('update chat' 
                , 'username':socket.username 
                , 'data':JSON.stringify(data));
```

and parse same string back to json form at recieving end via `JSON.parse` like

```
var objData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: hi,thx for help but i get this error undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: try `console.log` on the `data` before you try the `JSON.parse` and tell us what you got

Comment: plz i have other problem when i wan't to insrt in mongodb ValidationError: Validator "regexp" failed for path pseudo with value `{"username":"amine.was"}....pseudo : { type : String, match: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*$/ },

Comment: @amine: could you edit your question and provide more info. Or it will be better if you could post it as a new qn